# Convert A Grayscale Image To Colored In Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am using the following lines of code to convert a colored image into grayscale image :

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the Cover Image');
file = fullfile(PathName,FileName);
disp(['User selected : ', file]);
cover = imread(file);
%cover = double(cover);

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(uint8(cover),[]);
title('Cover image');


red = cover(:,:,1);
green = cover(:,:,2);
blue = cover(:,:,3);
a = zeros(size(cover, 1), size(cover, 2));

just_red = cat(3, red, a, a);
figure, imshow(just_red);

just_green = cat(3, a, green, a);
figure, imshow(just_green);

just_blue = cat(3, a, a, blue);
figure, imshow(just_blue);

[r1 r2 a] = size(just_red);
disp(a); disp(r1); disp(r2);
coverbw = rgb2gray(cover);

original = gray2rgb(coverbw);
figure, imshow(original);
```

After converting the original image to grayscale, I want to convert the grayscale image back into the original colored one. I tried using the following line of code to do the job :

```
original = gray2rgb(coverbw);
```

But I was getting the following error :

```
??? Undefined function or method 'gray2rgb' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Error in ==> main at 35
    original = gray2rgb(coverbw);
```

Can someone help me to get the original image from its grayscale version i.e. `coverbw` instead of combining the three separate components of red, green and blue color images ??

Thanks.

Comment: how do you expect to recover lost color information from the gray image?

Comment: Actually, I am doing arnold transform for image scrambling. That code is working for a 2-D image. After decrypting the original image,I am getting a grayscale image. But, instead I want a colored image. Is it possible to add colors to that grayscale image from the information that I am saving in red, green and blue colors ?

Comment: @Shai, I am saving the information of the image in red, green and blue arrays.. Can u help me to restore the colors back ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When converting RGB image to gray you **lose** color information per-pixel.
The gray value `I` per pixel `i, j` is determined by the formula:

```
I(i,j) = 0.299*R(i,j) + 0.587*G(i,j) + 0.114*B(i,j)
```

Mathematically, it means that if you know `R, G` and `B` you can determine `I`.
**But**, if you know only `I` you **cannot** recover `R`, `G` and `B` since you have a single equation with three unknowns and therefore there can be infinitely many possible color combinations that produce the same intensity `I`.

If you are working on scrambling of 2D images, you can treat each channel `R`, `G` and `B` as an independent 2D signal, scramble each one and then combine the reconstructed signals to a color image at the end by

```
rgb = cat(3, recoveredR, recoveredG recoveredB );
```

Comment: @competesingh you can do `rgb = just_red + just_green + just_blue;` according to the way you constructed these arrays in your question.

Comment: on using the code `rgb = cat(3, recoveredR, recoveredG recoveredB );` I am getting the following error : `??? Error using ==> imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData at 114
Unsupported dimension`.. Can u help me out ?? I am confused with this dimensional error .. I am unable to get it.

Comment: @competesingh what are the sizes of the components `R` `G` `B` you are using? are they 2D or 3D arrays?

Comment: is it possible to add the stored three components of colored image to the grayscale image ?? Is it possible to superimpose the 4 images(red, green, blue and grayscale) to get the original image ?

Comment: @competesingh if they are 3D arrays then their sizes should be `[128 128 3]` and not `[128 128]`. please take a moment to read carefully about RGB color space and the conversion to gray scale image, then try and figure out what you need to do.

Comment: You could perhaps pseudo-colour the image by using `imagesc` and specify a colour map.  Just throwing it out there as an alternative option.